# How to make boxes independent from those cell-formatting options?

Tags: front-end, formatting, cells, boxes, placeholder

In a cell whose `LanguageCategory` option is `"Input"`, boxes will be syntax-highlighted. Is there any way to diasble such cell-formatting behaviors for inner boxes?

**Additional Requirement**: No inline cells should be used. That makes the `Tab` key unable to be used for jumps between placeholders. (There're more side effects not mentioned for inline cells.)

### Example

```
(* highlighted *)
CellPrint@Cell[BoxData@RowBox@{"boxA", "boxB"}, "Input"]

(* disable highlighting for one box with inline cells *)
CellPrint@Cell[BoxData@RowBox@{"boxA", Cell[BoxData@"boxB", LanguageCategory -> None]}, "Input"]

(* jumps between placeholders fails, so I don't want to use inline cells *)
CellPrint@Cell[BoxData@RowBox@{"boxA\[Placeholder]", Cell[BoxData@"boxB\[Placeholder]", LanguageCategory -> None]}, "Input"]
```

### Other cell options to be screened

- ShowStringCharacters
- ... (Most of the options in `StyleData["Input"]` in `Core.nb`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you can use the `StyleBox`:

```
StyleBox["boxB", LanguageCategory -> None]
```

```
(*highlighted*)CellPrint@
 Cell[BoxData @ RowBox @ {"boxA", StyleBox["boxB", LanguageCategory -> None]},   "Input"]

(*jumps between placeholders works*)
CellPrint @  Cell[ BoxData @ RowBox @ {
  "boxA\[Placeholder]", 
  StyleBox["boxB\[Placeholder]", LanguageCategory -> None]
},"Input"]
```

[image]

Comment: I find that I'd underestimated `StyleBox` so much after having tried `Keys@Options@StyleBox`.